# Cursor expression in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor

How do I achieve the same as an Oracle cursor expression does in a MySQL database (version from 5.6 onwards)
below is a sample query of an Oracle cursor expression

```
SELECT department_name, CURSOR(SELECT salary, commission_pct 
   FROM employees e
   WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id)
   FROM departments d;
```

How can I achieve the same as this with a MySQL database?

if i execute this query on oracle below output i will be produced,
depart_name   cursor result

**MCA     { < SALARY=20000 , COMMISSION_PCT=2 > , < SALARY=40000,COMMISSION_PCT=20> ,}**

**BE     {< SALARY=20000,COMMISSION_PCT=2 >,}**

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: AFAIK - There is no equivalent in MySQL for CURSOR expressions. But specific problems can probably also be solved in MySQL in a different way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for the delay, if i execute it on oracle below output i will get,MCA {<SALARY=20000,COMMISSION_PCT=2>,<SALARY=40000,COMMISSION_PCT=20>,}
BE {<SALARY=20000,COMMISSION_PCT=2>,}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what a **CURSOR()** does in oracle because I've never touched oracle, but I don't know if it would help you but I think you wanted to join like this:

```
SELECT d.department_name, e.salary, e.commission_pct. 
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN employees e
ON (e.department_id = d.department_id);
```

I give you this link for more information on joints:
https://sql.sh/cours/jointures
and according to sql.sh:

> There are several methods to associate 2 tables together. Here is the
>   list of the different techniques that are used:
>
> - **INNER JOIN:** internal join to return the records when the condition is true in both tables. This is one of the most common
>     joins.
> - **CROSS JOIN:** cross join to make the Cartesian product of 2 tables. In other words, allows to join each row of a table with each
>     row of a    second table. Attention, the number of results is
>     generally very    high.
> - **LEFT JOIN (or LEFT OUTER JOIN):** external join to return all the records of the left table (LEFT = left) even if the condition is not
>     checked in the other table.
> - **RIGHT JOIN (or RIGHT OUTER JOIN):** External join to return all records in the right-hand table (RIGHT = right) even if the condition 
>     is not checked in the other table.
> - **FULL JOIN (or FULL OUTER JOIN) :** external join to return the results when the condition is true in at least one of the 2 tables.
> - **SELF JOIN :** allows to join a table with itself as if it were another table.
> - **NATURAL JOIN :** natural join between 2 tables if there is at least one column with the same name between the 2 SQL tables.
> - **UNION JOIN:** joint of union.

if you have any questions, I am available to answer them.

Comment: thanks @Dadinks but my required output is , f i execute it on oracle below output i will get ** MCA {<SALARY=20000,COMMISSION_PCT=2>,<SALARY=40000,COMMISSION_PCT=20>,} BE {<SALARY=20000,COMMISSION_PCT=2>,} **