# Exporting MySql table into JSON Object

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

how to convert my mysql table result into json Object in database level

for example ,

```sql
SELECT json_array(
         group_concat(json_object( name, email))
FROM ....
```

it will produce the result as

```
[ 
   { 
     "name": "something",
     "email": "someone@somewhere.net"
    }, 
   { 
     "name": "someone",
     "email": "something@someplace.com"
    }

]
```

but what i need is i need to given my own query which may contains functions, subqueries etc.

like in postgres `select row_to_json(select name,email,getcode(branch) from .....)` then i will get the whole result as json object

in mysql is there any possibilities to do like this?

```sql
select jsonArray(select name,email,getcode(branch) from .....)
```

Comment: Why did you tag 3 different MySQL versions, and MariaDB? Please tag only the one database/version that you are using.

Comment: @GMB I need to support all these versions and I know Json support is not available in mysql lower version(s)

Comment: @GMB do you have any idea on this, how we can achieve this in My Sql

Comment: Show an example of your complex query that needs to be converted to JSON. This is too broad without specifics.

Comment: @underscore_d first of all thanks for considering my question. no need for complex query and all. just for simple query itself , for example i having table called **department**  it has depid,deptname,salr etc.in below example i need to mention the name of the columns in that **json_object** function without mentioning  the columns i can give query which is dynamic for ex::  select deptid,depname from department , example 2 :::   SELECT department_name, CURSOR(SELECT salary, commission_pct 
   FROM employees e
   WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id)
   FROM departments d;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found in official Mysql 8 and 5.7 documentation that it supports casting to JSON type. It includes a JSON_ARRAY function in MySQL 8 and 5.7, and JSON_ARRAYAGG function in MySQL 8. Please see the full JSON functions reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html).

It means that does not exist an easy mysql built-in solution to the problem.

Fortunately, our colleagues started a similar discussion [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192208/mysql-return-json-from-a-standard-sql-query). Maybe you could find your solution there.

For one searching for well-defined attributes JSON casting, the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql).

Comment: thanks, but that is what i have mentioned already in question i can able to generate json like that but i need to mention the particular column names in that **json_object** function, but my requirement is my query is standard SQL format and its is dynamic like  this select deptid,depname, getDepCode(depcode) from department. that why i mentioned in postgres sql if we pass the sql query to **row_to_json()** function it will convert the result table to **json_array**

Comment: Sorry. Let me see more precise: All I found in the official doc, is that mysql supports only this kind of functions natively: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html.

It means that does not exist MySQL easily native support as Postgres supports.  

I will edit the question to be more precise. And will point to the other discussions on StackOverflow and StackExchange.

Comment: thank you @Erme Schultz,, do you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/62344730/9066195

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much about this issue.